# How do I autofocus a form control in angular 10, without use of the nativeElement

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

This is the example to using the native Element approach, I've tried it for a while it's not bad.
But would like to know if there is a form Control method provided by the forms library

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <input #myInput type="text" />
    <div> Some other content </div>
  `

})
export class MyComp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myInput') input: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.input.nativeElement,    
    'focus');
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use directly: `this.input.nativeElement.focus()`, but I don't know another way -well, you can use a directive, but always use nativeElement.focus()-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to focus it when the component is created you could create a directive for this and attach it to your input. For this particular case which is quite simple, the directive could be the following:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoFocus]',
})
export class AutoFocusDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  public focus(): void {
    (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).focus();
  }
}
```

If you need to interact with it you could add some public methods (to focus it later etc).

There's no way to never touch the DOM for that kind of thing, but a good way to do so is to abstract the fact that you're manipulating the DOM through a directive.